# Separate classes for Selenium WebDriver test cases using NUnit

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with NUnit. I just do not want to put all of my test cases i.e. my code in a single C# class. I want a class having driver initiation. Another class having Login test cases. Another class having Patient Form test cases. And so on.

When I use NUnit, it does not require Main method. It just call on methods on its own. How would I be able to access the driver in another class if I have created it in another class?

Will it be good performance-wise to create an object of Driver class in Login class?
I think this will kill the purpose of NUnit. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is

You can declare a Web Driver instance as a `Static` variable and use all over the packages. One thing keep in mind Static variable is a server side variable so nullify when you finish your execution.

Another efficient method is you can use `Java Reflection` API.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [PageObject model pattern](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) used for WebDriver. 
In that, you isolate your test specification code and test implementation code according to Pages. Your pageobjects are nothing but classes that represent a page/ higher-level section of your application. You initiate a WebDriver instance in the main test class and pass it's object to the PageObjects in their constructors.